# Why did Anand start with d4?

Tags: carlsen-anand-2014

As far as I remember, Anand was(is) primarily an 1.e4 player throughout his career. Yet in the first game of the Carlsen-Anand match he opted to open with 1.d4. What are the potential benefits of such an opening choice in a situation like this? Is Anand simply wary of having to face the Berlin Defense, or is there another benefit to choosing 1.d4?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: not the downvoter, but this is the question, which is impossible to answer reliably if you are not Anand.

Comment: Only Anand knows why. We can only speculate. My guess is that it is because 1. e4 didn't work for him in his last match with Carlsen. The only game where he had Carlsen in some sort of trouble playing White was when he played 1. d4. So it's logical for Anand to play 1. d4 in this match.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is indeed a very subjective question.

Comment: Leaving aside the subjectivity, there are extremely few top players that consistently choose an opening move over the rest. The first one that comes to mind is Mamedyarov, but nowadays Anand plays `1.e4` as much as `1.d4`.

Comment: I'm suggesting an edit that might help to make this question less subjective/reliant on Anand's preference by asking instead what the benefits are of choosing 1.d4 instead of 1.e4 at the start of a WC match.

Comment: This question was too subjective anyway, can an full moderator close it?

Comment: Can you delete it instead? It is pointless to lose points by downvotes, especially since you worked so hard to earn them. The question will never be rephrased into useful one anyway :(

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I cannot, since it has an answer. I need a mod to do it.

Comment: I don't think the question is so bad, but I'll vote to close it since the original poster has requested it.

Answer (score 5):

Anand primarily played 1. d4 in each of his 3 successful world championship matches between 2008 and 2012. In his 2013 match vs. Carlsen he favored 1. e4 before switching to 1. d4 for his last white of the match (game 9). Given the disastrous result of the 2013 match for him, I don't think it's surprising that he is apparently relying on 1. d4 this time.

Comment: Indeed! For me the question is: Why did Anand open with e4 last year?